# How to configure build.gradle.kts file in android programming

Tags: gradle-kotlin-dsl, android-build

I have initiated an android project in kotlin and my gradle file has the .kts extension . I am trying to add room dependency but i have accountered an error . Here is what i've done :

```
 implementation("androidx.room:room-runtime:2.6.1")
implementation("androidx.room:room-ktx:2.6.1")
kapt("androidx.room:room-compiler:2.5.2")
```

and this is the error message i got : Unresolved reference: kapt

here is the content of the build.gradle.kts(:app) file :

```
 plugins {
    id("com.android.application")
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android")

}

android {
    namespace = "com.yyyyy.xxxx"
    compileSdk = 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.yyyy.xxxx"
        minSdk = 29
        targetSdk = 34
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }

    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding = true
        buildConfig = true
    }


}

    dependencies {
    
        implementation("androidx.core:core-ktx:1.12.0")
        implementation("androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1")
        implementation("com.google.android.material:material:1.11.0")
        implementation("androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4")
        testImplementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")
        androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5")
        androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1")
    
        /* Navigation */
        implementation ("androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.7.6")
        implementation ("androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.7.6")
    
        /* Room */
        implementation("androidx.room:room-runtime:2.6.1")
        implementation("androidx.room:room-ktx:2.6.1")
        kapt("androidx.room:room-compiler:2.5.2")
    
    
    }
```

how could i resolve this ???

Comment: Did you apply the gradle kotlin-kapt plugin? Please post the complete content of your build.gradle.kts file.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the gradle plugin for [kotlin annotation processor (KAPT)](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/kapt.html).
Add the following line to your `plugins` section and it should work.

```
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt")
```

You might also have to set the plugin version to which ever Kotlin version you are using.

```
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt") version("x.x.x")
```